# read in column from csv file into bash script

Tags: bash, csv

In a bash script I want to loop over values I have stored in a csv file.  How can I import a column from a csv file into a bash script and then do something like:

```
for i in {column imported from csv}

do
mkdir "$i"
done
```

my csv file looks like this:

```
1, 3, 8
4, 6, 10
123, 6, 8
324, 9, 12
```

how do I import the first column to get:

```
for i in {1, 4, 123, 324}
```

Comment: Do you want the commas in the data or not?  3 of the 4 values in the hypothetical syntax have a comma after them, which might or might not be the comma in the data.

Comment: No I don't want the commas

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to loop, just use `cut` with `xargs`:

```
cut -d, -f1 file | xargs mkdir
```

To get the first column using a `for` loop:

```
while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
   echo "processing ${arr[0]}"
done < file
processing 1
processing 4
processing 123
processing 324
```

Change `echo` to whatever command you want to use inside the loop.

Comment: This is great if I was just making the directories, but I want the loop because I need to do other things with the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ for i in $(cut -d, -f1 file); do mkdir "$i"; ... ; done
```

or replace cut with awk

```
$ for i in $(awk -F, '{print $1}' file); do mkdir "$i"; ... ; done
```